# How to get specific key value from a nested TreeMap

Tags: java, nested, treemap

Say I have the TreeMap,

```
TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,String>>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

and there are two values,

```
mapToTree("1","1","1","111");
mapToTree("1","2","111",null);
```

where mapToTree is a method for storing values into the nested TreeMap.

I know that to get a value that is in the last value position I would do,

```
map.get("1").get("1").get("1");
```

but how would I get the key value in 1,2? Currently when I do

```
System.out.println(map.get("1").get("2"));
```

it prints "{111=null}."

Comment: That is the value. What do you want it print?

Comment: I am looking for only the string stored as the key.

Comment: Namely........?

Comment: I just want the key. The key is "111" in that position.

Comment: What if there are multiple keys?

Comment: There won't be.

Comment: Then why would you create a whole map for it?

Comment: It is simply what I need. I'm not here to ask if I should be using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can get the entire keySet and iterate

   ```
   map.get("1").get("2").keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. For the case if you are only interested in the first key, value pair you can use -

   ```
   System.out.println(map.get("1").get("2").firstKey());
   ```